# Launching parameters for FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

### Question :

Are there existing parameters for FTL to control things such as Screen Resolution ?

### Reason :

Im currently making a script for FTL in order to load/save my progression.
Since this requires multiple starts of the FTL's process and since I have an extended screen :
Each time I start again the process, the window is like in between both of my screens...
which is quite annoying.

Comment: Have you tried looking for an .ini file? That might be what you're looking for.

Comment: There is an ini file, but it seems to be the exact reproduction of the settings menu : 
fullscreen=0 
music=0 
sound=0 
altpause=0 
dialog_keys=1 
lowend=0 
logging=1 
ach_pop=1

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate. I've got FTL on my laptop at home. Give me a couple hours and I'll poke around too and see what I can find.

Comment: If you open your settings.ini file and add the lines
screen_x=<value>
screen_y=<value> does that sort it?

Comment: screen_x and screen_y properties inside settings.ini does not sort it

Answer (score 1):

[This may help you.](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Glossary:Borderless_fullscreen_windowed#AutoHotkey)

I hope you know how to use AutoHotkey scripts, or you may have to get lucky/ask another question with more information.

[The PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/FTL:_Faster_Than_Light#Borderless_fullscreen_windowed) also prescribes borderless fullscreen settings.ini changes that may work:

```
fullscreen=0
lastFullScreen=0
manual=1
screen_x=your x value screen resolution
screen_y=your y value screen resolution
windowed=1
stretched=1
```